# nth-child selector doesn't override html element style

Tags: css, parent-child, css-animations, combinators

```css
/* Core style */

#preview #icon {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.donut {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
.donut i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
}


/* Circle O Times icon */
.donut.circle-o-times i {
  border-radius: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.65);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.65);
  -o-transform: scale(0.65);
  transform: scale(0.65);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(3) {
  border-radius: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="preview">
    <i id="icon" class=" donut circle-o-times ">
    <i style="background-color:#FF6600"></i>
    <i style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)"></i>
    <i style="background-color:#FF6600"></i>
    <i style="background-color:#FF6600"></i>
    </i>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i'm trying to delete the color styles attributes form html and move them to the css before i animate the icon

when i specify background-color in css nth-childs and delete the html styles nothing works anymore

where am i going wrong?

Comment: you're not overriding any inline html style within the nth-child selector, all I can see is the border radius and transform, but in the html is the background-color.... so no overriding should happen...

Comment: Can you post a snippet that demonstrates the issue? Also, "nothing works anymore" could do with some elaboration.

Comment: the above code shows the original setup. if i delete the four html style attributes (which color the four "circle-o-times" css elements) and specify background-color in the corresponding css elements the icon collapses.

Comment: @mick OK, can you edit that into the question? That would make the matter much clearer. I'm not sure what happens though; normally an element won't change its sizes by just adding or removing a background color. Are you sure you're doing nothing else when you delete the style attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can not override style which is declared in html tag. If you want to override css then you have to add `background-color:#FF6600` in your class and then you can override it by using nth-child.
for example

```
<div id="preview">
<i id="icon" class=" donut circle-o-times ">
       <i class="differentclass"></i>
</i>
</div>
```

css

```
.differentclass{
    background-color:#FF6600;
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(1) {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: The OP says when they delete the html styles (by which I presume they mean the style attributes) nothing works anymore.

Comment: But he clearly says that 'when i specify background-color in css nth-childs and delete the html styles nothing works anymore
where am i going wrong?'

Comment: Also, you should emphasise that `!important` should only be used as a last resort (in case the html style attributes can't be deleted) or face serious downvoting!

Comment: i don't want to override the html style attributes; they have to go!

Comment: i need to create a clean piece of code to use in a wordpress theme and since i'm not familiar with that kind of coding i have to make sure that 1) all the customizations can be done in wordpress custom css and 2) the code is as clean as possible to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

here is the modified (not-working) version for html

```
<div id="preview">
<i id="icon" class=" donut circle-o-times "></i>
</div>
```

and for css

```
#preview #icon {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 250px;
width:250px;
height:250px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.donut {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms;
-moz-transition: all 500ms;
-o-transition: all 500ms;
transition: all 500ms;
}
.donut i {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 1;
background: #000000;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms;
-moz-transition: all 500ms;
-o-transition: all 500ms;
transition: all 500ms;
}
.donut.circle-o-times i {
border-radius: 0%;
background-color:#FF6600;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(1) {
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:#FFF;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
-moz-transform: scale(0.8);
-ms-transform: scale(0.8);
-o-transform: scale(0.8);
transform: scale(0.8);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(2) {
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:#FF6600;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
-moz-transform: scale(0.65);
-ms-transform: scale(0.65);
-o-transform: scale(0.65);
transform: scale(0.65);
}
.donut.circle-o-times i:nth-child(3) {
border-radius: 0%;
background-color:#FF6600;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5, 0.125);
}
```